# How to create Submenu in dropdown menu in bootstrap 5

Tags: drop-down-menu, navbar, bootstrap-5, submenu

``I'm stucked in creating submenu inside dropdown menu. Please anybody help me solve this problem.
the submenu is showing below the manin menu.
If i give display - none css then only it hides but after giving hover css then it doesnt shows.
please help.
`

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white navbar-light sticky-top py-0 pe-5">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand ps-5 me-0">
            <!-- <h1 class="text-white m-0">Industro</h1> -->
            <img src="/img/airboxlogo.png" width="170px" height="45px">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler me-0" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto p-4 p-lg-0">
                <a href="" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                <!-- <a href="" class="nav-item nav-link">About</a> -->
                <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Products</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu bg-light m-0">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Main Product 1
                            <div class="submenu dropdown-menu dropend">
                                <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu dropend">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Product 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub product 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                         </a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Main product 2</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Main product 3</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Main product 3</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Main product 4</a>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">About </a>
               
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Services</a>
                
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact us</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary px-3 d-none d-lg-block">Download Catalogue</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

`This is CSS`

```
.submenu .dropdown-item
{
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu ul li >.dropdown-item:hover
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-link{
  color: #fff;
}
.dropend .dropdown-toggle{
  color: salmon;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.dropdown-item:hover{
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  color: #fff;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
  display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu, .dropend:hover > .dropdown-menu{
  display: block;
  margin-top: .125em;
  margin-left: .125em;
}
@media screen and (min-width:769px) {
  .dropend:hover > .dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
  .dropend .dropdown-toggle{
    margin-left: .5em;
  }
}
```

```html
  <html>
  <head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <main>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: salmon;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand fw-bold" href="#">Navbar DropDown</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropend">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropend">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item dropend">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                          Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                          </li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```